# How to get one function to deal with multiple instances of HTML?

Tags: jquery

On a Gallery page I have multiple instances of the 'gallery block' like so:

```
    <!-- gallery block -->
    <div class="gallery">

      <div class="thumbnails">
        <a href="images/test-image-1.jpg"><img src="images/test-image-1.jpg" alt="Test Coach"></a>
        <a href="images/test-image-2.jpg"><img src="images/test-image-2.jpg" alt="Test Coach"></a>
        <a href="images/test-image-3.jpg"><img src="images/test-image-3.jpg" alt="Test Coach"></a>
        <a href="images/test-image-4.jpg"><img src="images/test-image-4.jpg" alt="Test Coach"></a>
        <a href="images/test-image-5.png"><img src="images/test-image-5.png" alt="Test Coach"></a>
      </div>

      <div class="mainImage"></div>

    </div>
    <!-- /gallery block -->
```

And in my script file I have the following which works fine for one instances of the 'gallery block':

```
    (function() {
      'use strict';
        if (jQuery('body.gallery-page').length > 0) {

          jQuery('.thumbnails a').click(function(evt) {
            //don't follow link
             evt.preventDefault();
             //get path to new image
             var imgPath = jQuery(this).attr('href');
             //get reference to old image
             var oldImage = jQuery('.mainImage img');

               //create HTML for new image
               var newImage = jQuery('<img src="' + imgPath +'">');
               //make new image invisible
               newImage.hide();
               //add to the .mainImage div
               jQuery('.mainImage').prepend(newImage);
               //fade in new image
               newImage.fadeIn(1000);

               //fade out old image and remove from DOM
               oldImage.fadeOut(1000,function(){
                 jQuery(this).remove();
                });
          }); // end click

          jQuery('.thumbnails a:first').click();

    }

    })(jQuery);
```

But how do I get the above to deal with lots of instances of the 'gallery block'?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [jQuery.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('div.gallery').each(function() {
    // Your method here
});
```

And don't forget to replace `jQuery('.thumbnails a')` with `jQuery(this).('.thumbnails a')`

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities. The answer with an each loop is already mentioned, but I'm not a fan of that answer for this specific case.

The most easy thing to do right now is to add the following line within your click handler:

```
var obj = jQuery(this).closest('.gallery');
```

After that, to change the contents of `.mainImage` you could select it with `obj.find('.mainImage')`.

Doing it this way, leaves you with just one click handler for all your galleries.

Comment: Thanks but how do I define `obj` if the `var obj = jQuery(this).closest('.gallery');` comes after it?

Comment: You need to add it right after this line: `jQuery('.thumbnails a').click(function(evt) {`

Comment: then do I use `obj.find('.mainImage')` like `jQuery(obj.find('.mainImage')).prepend(newImage);` ?

Comment: No, it would be `obj.find('.mainImage').prepend(newImage);`